# Merging/Joining GeoJSON and JSON?

Tags: geojson, json

I want OSM administrative boundaries from http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/area/14455.html.
I can get the geodata in different formats there, but the attribute data always is a separate JSON file. I want them both in just one file, or to be able to merge the information.

I haven't found a solution to merge the GeoJSON.

What's the workflow to get the two files joined and saved as a shapefile, for example?

Comment: can you pls post which geojson and json file that you wanna merge?

Comment: Sure I can. This is the JSON-File http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/area/14455  And this is the GeoJSON http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/area/14455.geojson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [this python script](https://gist.github.com/migurski/3759608) to merge the jsons together.

Then, it's your personal preference for how to convert it into a shapefile.

You can go with ogr2ogr like:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp raw.geojson
```

or if you're more comfortable with a GUI, you can open the json in qgis and save as a shapefile.

Answer (score 6):

i dont know where you want to merge but you can do it with python as following code.

```
merged = {
   firstObj : {"parent_area": null, "generation_high": 1, "all_names": {"default": ["OSM Default", "South Georgia"]}, "id": 14455, "codes": {"osm_rel": "1983629"}, "name": "South Georgia", "country": "G", "type_name": "OSM Administrative Boundary Level 3", "generation_low": 1, "country_name": "Global", "type": "O03"},    
   secondObj : { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -37.652271, -54.065565 ], [ -37.649751, -54.066685 ], [ -37.644852, -54.065705 ], [ -37.644572, -54.064725 ], [ -37.652271, -54.065565 ] ] ], [ [ [ -38.297102, -53.993427 ], [ -38.295513, -53.992544 ], [ -38.294201, -53.992191 ], [ -38.294226, -53.991661 ], [ -38.293848, -53.991661 ] ] ] ] }
};
```

Code:

```
import json

merged = { 'firstObj ' : obj1, 'secondObj' : obj2 }
json.dumps(merged)
```