# Joining GeoJSON and JSON at client end for Choropleth Map in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, json

This is not a duplicate of [Merging/Joining GeoJSON and JSON?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41403) because I need to join on client side.

I want to develop a [choropleth map](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/). I am using the same tutorial of Leaflet. I am also using the same [statesData](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/us-states.js) provided in that tutorial. The problem is value. I am getting an API which providing me the value of states. The 2nd JSON is providing me the id of states and its corresponding value. I want to visualize the choropleth map using these instead of Density value given in the statesData.js file.

{"id":"01","value":130.36},{"id":"02","value":125.36},{"id":"03","value":525.36}

How can I put this value to obtain a choropleth map instead of using density that showed in the tutorial?

Comment: Can you link an example complete JSON response from the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since GeoJSON is based on JSON, you are simply looking for joining two JSON objects. I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450060/how-to-join-two-javascript-objects-without-using-jquery) question is almost similar with yours and there are alternative solutions(pure js or using jQuery) .

Comment: GeoJSON is based on JSON but in GeoJSON feature collection that is a special format that can easily be read by different GIS libraries mainly Leaflet. I was stuck there. One is simply a JSON format and another is GeoJSON feature collection.

Comment: I think that looping over features of feature collection similar to the one of the answers at the link will solve the problem. I'll try to implement working code when I have access to a computer.

Comment: Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/L9tamn7a/22/

Answer (score 0):

Since there are not that many values the simplest solution would be to create lookup array for JSON data:

```
var array = [{"id":"01","value":130.36},{"id":"02","value":125.36},{"id":"03","value":525.36}];
var lookup = {};
for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    lookup[array[i].id] = array[i];
}
```

Now you can get value for some lookup_id where you need it by simple object reference:

```
desired_value = lookup[lookup_id].value;
```